# Html Table tbody not 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table but it is not 100% and the tbody size it is: 485x170px,

can someone help me to make this tbody 100%?

```
<thead> needs to be fixed as now.
```

I need have scrool and the tbody need to stay on the size of: `height: calc(100vh - 513px);`
[click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnD4u.png)

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ab1Lsn0h/2/

css:

```
.staff table tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: block;
  height: calc(100vh - 513px);
}

.staff tbody > tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="panel panel-default staff">
    <div class="panel-heading">test</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>name 1</td>
            <td>name 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name 1</td>
            <td>name 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name 1</td>
            <td>name 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name 1</td>
            <td>name 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name 1</td>
            <td>name 2</td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have to use tables for it? may I suggest an approach without table?

Comment: I have to use tables unfortunately, but what is your approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove your `display: block;` and `display: table;`.

You are converting tr in table, this is wrong.

Comment: but I need scroll in my tbody understand? and the thead need be fixed  so this was the only way i could do,